# Library for converting from FBX to 3MF programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, 3d, type-conversion, fbx

I'm coding a UWP app using C# and I need to display some 3D models on a map. This map component only accepts 3MF 3D models, but the models that I have are in FBX format, so I need to find a way of performing this conversion programmatically (in code), since many more models will come in the future and manual conversion is not an option.

I have been told that UWP itself does not include a tool that carries out this kind of conversion. Are there any libraries out there that could do the trick? I need something that, given a FBX file, produces an equivalent 3MF file.

P.S: I have done some research and found a library called *assimp*, which appears to support FBX to 3MF conversions, but I have not been able to get it working (I had problems related to CMake and MinGW, so I couldn't even try it).

Comment: Currently, we have not provided such api to convert FBX to 3MF directly within UWP platform, but you could try to convert it with online tool before added to the project.

Comment: The "hardest" part is getting the FBX reader... there are free code on Git but it is HEAVY and mind buggling.... You can also find 3MF file reader/writter on Git.
Now the "HARDEST" part would be to make the bridge between the two data structures depending on what you're willing to discard (FBX can contain animations for example, and i don't think 3MF can).
Soooo... elbow grease is needed ^^